# Phonegap & RaphaelJS slowdown

Tags: javascript, cordova, raphael, zepto

After building and running my app, there appears to be a major slowdown after dragging a raphaelJS object a few times.
Ive changed from JQuery + JQMobile to zepto but im still getting the slowdowns. 
It works fine on PC so i doubt anyone could replicate the issue in JSFiddle, if people want to test the app i will provide the build.phonegap link in a comment below.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <script src="js/zepto.min.js"></script>
        <!-- // <script src="js/hammer.min.js"></script> -->
        <script src="js/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
        <title>Mobile OneStop</title>
    </head>
    <body >         
        <div style=" border:1px solid #BBB; width:500px; height:500px;" id="Canvas">
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

The reason i delete the circle and then add a new one is to extend the amount of times it can be dragged before the slow down occurs, without it you can only get 1-2 drags and then it slows to a halt.

```
var MapView;
var canvasW;
var canvasH;

var circle;
var MapView, Background;

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    //For mobile devices document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    CreateCanavs();
});

function onDeviceReady() {
    CreateCanavs();
}

function CreateCanavs() {

    MapView = Raphael("Canvas", 500, 500);
    canvasW = MapView.width;
    canvasH = MapView.height;

    var circle = MapView.circle(100, 100, 20).attr({
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        "stroke-width": '2'
    });


    var circle1 = MapView.circle(300, 300, 20).attr({
        fill: 'blue',
        stroke: 'black',
        "stroke-width": '2'
    });

    circle.drag(onMove, onStart, onEnd);
    circle1.drag(onMove, onStart, onEnd);
}


function onMove(dx, dy) {
    var nowX;
    var nowY;
    var radius = this.attr("r");
    var boundX = canvasW - radius;
    var boundY = canvasH - radius;

    if (this.attr("cx") > canvasW || this.attr("cy") > canvasH) {
        this.attr('cx', this.ox + dx);
        this.attr('cy', this.oy + dy);
    } else {

        nowX = Math.min(boundX, this.ox + dx);
        nowX = Math.max(radius, nowX);
        nowY = Math.min(boundY, this.oy + dy);
        nowY = Math.max(radius, nowY);
        this.attr({
            "cx": nowX,
            "cy": nowY
        });
    }
}

function onStart() {
    this.ox = this.attr("cx");
    this.oy = this.attr("cy");
}

function onEnd() {
    var id = this.id;
    console.log(id);
    var x = this.attr("cx");
    var y = this.attr("cy");
    this.remove();

    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var col = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        col += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }


    var circle = MapView.circle(x, y, 20).attr({
        fill: col,
        stroke: 'black',
        "stroke-width": '2'
    });
    console.log(circle.attr("fill"));

    circle.drag(onMove, onStart, onEnd);
    circle.id = id;
}
```

Comment: It does require some access but they do nothing and are just in place for the offical version.
https://build.phonegap.com/apps/621133/share

And here is the github repo so you can check it out further: https://github.com/sidecore/OnestopTesting

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the reason of the slowdown, however you can perform small workaround to make it work a little bit faster.

```
//create array of planned updates
var plannedUpdates = []

//create function to cancel pending updates
var cancelPending = function(){
    for(var i = plannedUpdates.length - 1; i> -1;--i ){ 
        var plannedUpdate =plannedUpdates.pop();
        window.clearTimeout(plannedUpdate )
    }
}
//set update frequency as interval between updates
var updateFrequency = 100;

//modify your onMove function to plan updates instead of executing them immediatly:

function onMove(dx, dy) {
    var circle = this;
    cancelPending();
    plannedUpdates.push(window.setTimeout(function(){
        planUpdate(dx,dy,circle)
    }, updateFrequency));
}

var planUpdate = function(dx,dy, circle){
    this = circle
    var nowX;
    var nowY;
    var radius = this.attr("r");
    var boundX = canvasW - radius;
    var boundY = canvasH - radius;

    if (this.attr("cx") > canvasW || this.attr("cy") > canvasH) {
        this.attr('cx', this.ox + dx);
        this.attr('cy', this.oy + dy);
    } else {

        nowX = Math.min(boundX, this.ox + dx);
        nowX = Math.max(radius, nowX);
        nowY = Math.min(boundY, this.oy + dy);
        nowY = Math.max(radius, nowY);
        this.attr({
            "cx": nowX,
            "cy": nowY
        });
    }
}
```

You may need to tweak the updateFrequency to make it work as desired

EDIT!!
Oops I've  written setInterval where I meant setTimeout . Fixed!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, the slow down still occurs after a few drags.